# Can My email-id Subscribe Orion

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Can my email-id subscribe to Orion. So that if any changes occurs in Orion i can get an email something like that.
Also is there any other GE in Fiware which can do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the Perseo GE , which is CEP based on Esper

https://github.com/Ficodes/perseo-core

https://github.com/Ficodes/perseo-fe